# Debian 9 LXDE upon login message directory not found

Tags: debian, lxde

I have a debian 9 LXDE on Dell Laptop - installation that has started showing message after I login indicating a random directory under my home directory is not found.

e.g.  /home/tom/max not found - sometimes instead of /max it shows non-printable characters.

Sometimes there is no message pop-up and sometimes there is.

I tried to find in /var/log/under various logs but there is nothing coming up..

Any pointers to find a log or how to trace this?

Comment: Did you run `dmsg`?

Answer (score 0):

Run [dmesg](https://wiki.debian.org/dmesg), which is the log file you need, and search for your error message.